# Is it possible to merge two datasets using left join and rolling up the second data set based on a common field?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'd like to merge two datasets, but the second dataset can have multiple rows that can be joined to one item in the first data set.

For example, I'd like to merge the below datasets where the second data set has multiple items for one item in the first dataset:

```
data_set1 = [{'name':'A','id':1},{'name':'B','id':2}]
data_set2 = [{'product':'apple','id':1},{'product':'banana','id':1},{'product':'banana','id':2}]
```

I'd like to add 'product' to the first dataset, but if there are multiple in the second dataset to just combine the words into one item.

desired_data_set =

```
[{'name':'A','id':1,'product':'applebanana'},{'name':'B','id':2,'banana'}]
```

When I do the following, only one of the results are returned

```
select 
name,id,data_set2.product
from data_set1 
left join 
data_set2 on data_set2.id = data_set1.id
```

Comment: That query should return 3 records.  Are you sure that it only returns one? I am quite sure you did not execute that exact SQL, since it references `id` without alias and which can belong to either table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a chance to try the following and I can't event post this as a comment (because of my rep points). Can you try the following?

```
select 
name, data_set1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(data_set2.product) as product
from data_set1 
left join 
data_set2 on data_set2.id = data_set1.id
group by name, id, data_set2.product
```

Comment: Put the table name in front of `id`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a STUFF function if you are on MS SQL. Stuff allows you to take multiple rows and Pipe, XML or comma separate them in one Column.

Comment: Provide an example please!